# Prevent re-render when the parent state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

**Background:**

I'm building a real time image classification app for food items with react-native and the tensorflow [HOC Camera](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/0.2.1/#cameraWithTensors).

I'm using this [tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/real-time-image-classification-tensorflow-daniel-wind/?utm_campaign=React%2BNative%2BNow&utm_medium=web&utm_source=React_Native_Now_69) as a basis which includes a github repo where you can test it via Expo:

Basically, I want the camera preview to remain live and display predictions from the tensorflow model live. There is a function that is called each frame and predicts it. **I can console.log() the predictions live but displaying them using a state variable causes the camera to re-render every prediction.**

This is obviously poor user experience as only the text containing the prediction should change, the camera doesn't need to rerender. I've tried using React.memo() but that provides a 'Performance hint' and does not guarantee the camera component will not rerender.

**Code:**

```
const handleCameraStream = async(tensor) => {
  const prediction = await mobilenetModel.classify(tensor, 1);

  console.log(`prediction: prediction}`);//works live

  setWord(prediction);//causes rerender of camera
}
```

}

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    //Want this to update continuously (every time word is updated)
    <Text style={styles.wordTextField}>{word}</Text> 
    //DON'T want the camera to re-mount every state change
    <TensorflowCamera onReady={(imageAsTensors) => handleCameraStream(imageAsTensors)} /> 
  </View>  
</View>
```

**EDIT:** I was able to work around calling a setState by using MobX to implement a simple global state. Basically I have a class (WordStore) in App.js which is passed into a Camera component and TextDisplay component. The camera component is able to change the store's properties without triggering a rerender and TextDisplay is able to get these changes as the camera remains mounted.

You can try it out by cloning [this repo](https://github.com/JJwilkin/Pictionary-modification).

Simply `npm install` and `expo start`

Comment: Please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example for your issue. If you can, including a *running* [Expo Snack](https://expo.io/) could be beneficial as well.

Comment: @DrewReese I've added some code snippets to illustrate the basic idea, basically I want the {word} to be updated every prediction but that setWord() call ends up rerendering the <TensorflowCamera /> everytime, which doesn't happen with console.log

Comment: I think Brouwer has it below. You are creating a new `onReady` prop callback each time this parent component renders. Try `onReady={handleCameraStream}` and if that still doesn't help, memoize the `handleCameraStream` callback function with `useCallback` so you are passing a stable callback reference to the `TensorflowCamera` component.

Comment: Thanks, those didn't work but I was able to get it working with MobX. https://github.com/JJwilkin/Pictionary-modification is a demo with expo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around calling a setState by using MobX to implement a simple global state. Basically I have a class (WordStore) in App.js which is passed into a Camera component and TextDisplay component. The camera component is able to change the store's properties without triggering a rerender and TextDisplay is able to get these changes as the camera remains mounted.

You can try it out by cloning this repo: https://github.com/JJwilkin/Pictionary-modification

Simply `npm install` and `expo start`

Answer (score 0):

```
<TensorflowCamera onReady={(imageAsTensors) => handleCameraStream(imageAsTensors)} />
```

This might cause unnecessary re-renders of `TensorflowCamera` because you are passing in a new function on each render of the component that has this snippet in it. You can either pass in `handleCameraStream` directly or wrap it with the `useCallback` hook.

Comment: I've passed the handleCameraStream directly but it still rerenders on state change, i'm considering implementing MobX so the camera can alter a global state without triggering a rerender of itself

Comment: You can always try the package "why-did-you-render" to find out why re-renders happen exactly... see https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render

Answer (score 0):

You can create a child component and wrap with memo or use useEffect to avoid re-rendering when prop changes.

Comment: I've tried putting the camera in a child component but anytime the parent state updates the camera still rerenders. I've wrapped in a React.Memo but the issue still happens

Comment: use second parameter of memo which is smilar to should compont update life cycle .